# Scaleway scw init Inside Docker Container

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile

I am trying to make the Scaleway CLI installed as part of a docker image I'm building to run Azure Pipelines.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# To make it easier for build and release pipelines to run apt-get,
# configure apt to not require confirmation (assume the -y argument by default)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        jq \
        git \
        iputils-ping \
        libcurl4 \
        libicu60 \
        libunwind8 \
        netcat\
        docker.io \
        s3cmd

# Install Scaleway CLI
RUN curl -o /usr/local/bin/scw -L "https://github.com/scaleway/scaleway-cli/releases/download/v2.1.0/scw-2-1-0-linux-x86_64"
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/scw

# Add config for Scaleway CLI
RUN mkdir -p ./config
RUN mkdir -p ./config/scw
COPY ./config/config.yaml $HOME/.config/scw/config.yaml
RUN scw init

# Add private key for SSH connections
COPY ./config/id_rsa $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

# Config s3cmd
COPY ./config/.s3cfg $HOME/.s3cfg

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

The key section being:

```
# Install Scaleway CLI
RUN curl -o /usr/local/bin/scw -L "https://github.com/scaleway/scaleway-cli/releases/download/v2.1.0/scw-2-1-0-linux-x86_64"
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/scw

# Add config for Scaleway CLI
RUN mkdir -p ./config
RUN mkdir -p ./config/scw
COPY ./config/config.yaml $HOME/.config/scw/config.yaml
RUN scw init
```

The `config.yaml` file referenced above looks like the following (minus the real values of course):

```
access_key: <key>
secret_key: <secret>
default_organization_id: <orgId>
default_project_id: <projectId>
default_region: nl-ams
default_zone: nl-ams-1
```

However, when it executes `RUN scw init`, the output is `Invalid email or secret-key: ''`

I have tried without running `scw init` at all, but then calls to `scw` fail, saying

> Access key is required
>
> Details: Access_key can be initialised using the command "scw init".
>
> After initialisation, there are three ways to provide access_key:
>
> - with the Scaleway config file, in the access_key key: /root/.config/scw/config.yaml;
> - with the SCW_ACCESS_KEY environement variable;
>
> Note that the last method has the highest priority.
>
> More info:
> https://github.com/scaleway/scaleway-sdk-go/tree/master/scw#scaleway-config
>
> Hint: You can get your credentials here:
> https://console.scaleway.com/account/credentials

Which admittedly is one of the better error messages I've seen, but nonetheless has not helped me.  I am going to try the Environment Variable approach, which I suspect may do the trick, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong with this config.yaml file.

Lastly... someone with more rep than me needs to create the tag "scaleway".  Hard to reference the actual technology in question when the tag doesn't exist.

Comment: One quick question, are you succeed to build this Dockerfile from Visual Studio？

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT, I am using Visual Studio Code, actually, so I've been building it from the command line using `docker image build -t dockeragent:latest .`, and no, it will not build as it fails on the line `RUN scw init` with the error described in the post.